# Generating change set between two maps

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What is the best/cleanest/most-efficient way to detect changes between two `Map` instances. I.e.

```
val before = Map(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar", 3 -> "baz")
val after  = Map(1 -> "baz", 2 -> "bar", 4 -> "boo")

// not pretty:
val removed = before.keySet diff after.keySet
val added   = after.filterNot { case (key, _) => before contains key }
val changed = (before.keySet intersect after.keySet).flatMap { key =>
  val a = before(key)
  val b = after (key)
  if (a == b) None else Some(key -> (a, b))
}
```

Comment: As a *very general* approach, you might be interested to look at [Merkle trees](http://distributeddatastore.blogspot.ru/2013/07/cassandra-using-merkle-trees-to-detect.html)

Comment: Wie? Like Mutti, our chancellor? *Schock*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea. It probably takes O(N * log N) with N = max(before.size, after.size):

```
sealed trait Change[+K, +V]
case class Removed[K   ](key: K)                      extends Change[K, Nothing]
case class Added  [K, V](key: K, value : V)           extends Change[K, V]
case class Updated[K, V](key: K, before: V, after: V) extends Change[K, V]

def changes[K, V](before: Map[K, V], after: Map[K, V]): Iterable[Change[K, V]] ={
  val b = Iterable.newBuilder[Change[K, V]]
  before.foreach { case (k, vb) =>
    after.get(k) match {
      case Some(va) if vb != va => b += Updated(k, vb, va)
      case None                 => b += Removed(k)
      case _ =>
    }
  }
  after.foreach { case (k, va) =>
    if (!before.contains(k)) b += Added(k, va)
  }
  b.result()
}

changes(before, after).foreach(println)

// Updated(1,foo,baz)
// Removed(3)
// Added(4,boo)
```

Comment: That looks about right, but it's `O(N) + O(M * log M)` where `M` is the size of the changeset.

Comment: @RexKerr if I have `before.foreach` outside (O(N)) and call `after.get` inside (O(log N)), that is already O(N * log N), right? With M <= N I believe O(N * log N) is still the worst case...

Comment: You're using a map with `O(log N)` get?  Then you can use a sorted map your other operations stay the same order, but you can do this with iteration in `O(N)`.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice hash-map get is constant :-O