# Compare two Maps in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there any pre-defined function that I can use to compare two Maps based on the key and give me the difference? Right now, I iterate Map1 and foreach key, I check if there is an element in Map2 and I pattern match to find the difference. Is there a much elegant way to do this?

Comment: show you code of pattern matching

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580391/generating-change-set-between-two-maps/24580496), although that doesn't have a good answer yet.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Consider the difference between the maps converted into sets of tuples,

```
(m1.toSet diff m2.toSet).toMap
```

Comment: Bear in mind the output that you'd get from the diff method will vary depending on which object you call the diff method on i.e. m2.toSet diff m1.toSet would produce a different result.

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
val diff = (m1.keySet -- m2.keySet) ++ (m2.keySet -- m1.keySet)
```

`diff` contains the elements that are in `m1` and not in `m2` and that are in `m2` and not in `m1`.

Comment: `--` is deprecated in 2.9 and I think removed from 2.10, you should use `m1.keySet.filterNot(m2.keySet)`

Comment: really? it is in 2.11.5: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map

Answer (score 5):

This solution looks like right way:

```
scala> val x = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c")
x: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c)

scala> val y = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 4 -> "d")
y: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b, 4 -> d)

scala> val diff : Map[Int, String] = x -- y.keySet
diff: Map[Int,String] = Map(3 -> c)
```

Found it here https://gist.github.com/frgomes/69068062e7849dfe9d5a53bd3543fb81

Answer (score 2):

I think the `--` operator will do what you're looking for: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map@--(xs:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[A]):Repr

Although this will probably only work given the assumption that Map2 is always a subset of Map1...