# How to get the differences between two ObjectNode jsons in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I want to get the differences between two Jsons in a readable format. The answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969020/16305508) uses Java Maps. I tried converting ObjectNodes to Scala Maps with no success:

```
val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
val jsonNode = objectMapper.readValue(expectedJson, classOf[ObjectNode])
val otherNode = objectMapper.readTree(serviceJson).asInstanceOf[ObjectNode]
val converted = objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode, new TypeReference[Map[String, Any]] {})
```

Is there a way to convert an ObjectNode into a map so that I can use, for example, the Guava function given in the other answer? Maybe there is a simpler way to compare and get the difference between two Jsons in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to register `DefaultScalaModule` module. You can find it on Maven repository page: [Jackson Module Scala](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala).

When you register it you can easily deserialise `JSON` directly to the `Map`. Of course, root `JSON` node must be a `JSON Object`.

For example, let's assume we have two `JSON` payloads:

```json
{
  "field": "https://somethingh.com",
  "type": "object",
  "metaType": "object"
}
```

and

```json
{
  "type2": "object",
  "metaType": "object2"
}
```

We can read it as shown below:

```scala
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

import java.io.File
import scala.collection.immutable

object JsonScalaApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val jsonFile = new File("./src/main/resources/test.json")
    val jsonFile2 = new File("./src/main/resources/test2.json")
    val mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
      .addModule(DefaultScalaModule)
      .build()
    val map1 = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, classOf[immutable.HashMap[String, Any]])
    val map2 = mapper.readValue(jsonFile2, classOf[immutable.HashMap[String, Any]])
    val diff1 = (map1.toSet diff map2.toSet).toMap
    val diff2 = (map2.toSet diff map1.toSet).toMap

    println(map1)
    println(map2)
    println(diff1)
    println(diff2)
  }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Map(field -> https://somethingh.com, type -> object, metaType -> object)
Map(type2 -> object, metaType -> object2)
Map(field -> https://somethingh.com, type -> object, metaType -> object)
Map(type2 -> object, metaType -> object2)
```

You can use custom implementation to find all differences from linked question.

See also:

- [Compare two Maps in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827462/compare-two-maps-in-scala)